# How to speed up these ActiveRecord queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have three tables in my database: values, keys, and sources. Both keys and sources have many values. sources has a datetime column called file_date. For each key, I have to select all values that have a source that is between a specific date range (usually within two years). Not all dates within that range have a source, and not all sources have a value. I need to create an array that contains all values from within that range.

I at first tried to simply query the entire sources array at once, like so:

```
Value.where(key: 1, source: sources_array)
```

However, since there are several values that are nil, it simply returned records that have a value at that date.

So now, I've created an array containing all of the sources between that date range. Days that don't have a source simply have nil. Then, for each key, I iterate through the sources array, returning the value that matches that foo and source. That is obviously not ideal, and it takes about 7 seconds for the page to load.

Here is that code:

```
sources.map do |source|
  Value.where(source: source, key: key)
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also generate a single SQL query if you only need to retrieve the data and getting back arrays will suffice.

```
output = []

sources.each do |source|   
  output << "select * from values where (source like #{source} and key like #{key})"   
end

result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(output.join(" union ")).to_a
```

Comment: I got this error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  memory exhausted at or near "sources"`

Comment: You could try changing " union " to " union all ", in reference to this SE question:

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42852/postgres-9-2-select-multiple-specific-rows-in-one-query

That seems to be the common way to combine multiple select queries in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

The big issue with your `.map` is that it runs several queries, instead of one query with all the results you want. With each additional query, you add the overhead of sending the request to the database and receiving the response back. What you need to do is generate the query in a way that it returns *all* the results you may be looking for, and then dealing with any grouping or sorting application side.

Comment: I had tried that. I can't find anything that will have ActiveRecord return nil if it can't find anything.

Comment: If it can't find anything, it should return an object that is the equivalent of an empty array. You can call `.to_a` to get an array, or call `.empty?` which will return true when there are no results

Comment: There are results, but the source array has some values that are nil (because there was no source for that day). ActiveRecord simply ignores the nil values in the array. Also, there are some sources that don't have a value for that key that day.

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping your queries in a single transaction:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  sources.map do |source|
    Value.where(source: source, key: key)
  end
end
```

Comment: I just tried that, and it still clocks in at 7 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I'll need to refactor this like crazy, but I have something that has cut it down to 3 seconds:

```
  source_ids = sources.map do |source|
    if source
      source.id
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  values = Value.where(source: sources, key: key)
  value_sources = values.pluck(:source_id)
  value_decimals = values.pluck(:value_decimal)

  source_ids.map do |id|
    index = value_sources.index(id)

    if index
      value_decimals[index]
    else
      nil
    end
  end
```